# Completely override Maven Release lifecycle

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

In effort to customize the release of a project I came across the following article:

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/using-the-maven-release-plugin-things-to-know/

In essence the following assumptions are made for using the default release plugin:

- Your codebase is going to be versioned and released as a “unit”.
- You are using an SCM tool and a repository manager.
- You are performing your release from a single, “versionable” unit in SCM.
- You are using standard version numbers
- You are publishing artifacts to a repository

In mostly all these cases, our project does not meet these assumptions. We want to use a custom version schema (independent of SCM, maven, etc). Deploy the artifacts to a filesystem (not a repository). Not have maven mess around with SCM at all. Etc.

As recommended, we should probably define our own release lifecycle. Therefore I am assuming we would need to override the maven default lifecycle release phase to run our plugin. I guess I am missing the location of the required documentation. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing may be too radical to be worth doing within Maven, you may find yourself effectively writing a parallel build system simply triggered from Maven.

Assuming the effort is worth it - I would start by configuring the various plugins (most of Maven's functionality is delivered through plugins, triggered by phases in the lifecycle) and have them execute at a different goals within different phases. You may need to write Maven plugins to do whatever you want that doesn't already exist; which I expect you'll need to do in such a radical case.

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: You may be right. After re-evaluating, I could simply write our own "release" plugin and have that executed at an appropriate life cycle phase.